# Any way to hide test classes from the Hierarchy View in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gridview, view, hierarchy

I love Eclipse's hierarchy view which quickly shows all the subtypes and supertypes of my Java classes and interfaces.  However, the results I am looking for are made confusing by the fact they also show all the types from my unit tests.  While I find this helpful at time, I mostly find it annoying.  Any way to filter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hierarchy View, select the menu, and then choose "Select a Working Set".  Create a new Working Set that includes everything except the Test classes.  Use the new Working Set.

Comment: Works like a charm -- didn't understand that the "working set" can apply solely to the Hierarchy View and not to anything else in the workspace.  Thanks.