# Force Eclipse to ignore tests classes for Java search

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got following structure in Eclipse project

```
  - /src/main/java
  - /src/test/java
```

When I open call hierarchy or using java search, search result contains classes from **/src/test/java** classes. The same true for type hierarchy and others searches.

There are numbers of unit tests and I don't want to see classes from **/src/test/java** packages in search result.

The most straightforward way - simply exclude it from build path. Also there are filters for call hierarchy, however I was not able to find them for simple java search. Also filters relies on name pattern, which is not very good though.

I am looking for more convenient way

Comment: For Hierarchy View, you can apparently define a working set to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098313/any-way-to-hide-test-classes-from-the-hierarchy-view-in-eclipse?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your test folder, go to properties and check the "Derived" checkbox. Then click ok.

[image]

Or you can create 2 working sets. 1 set for your code and a second one for your tests. Then when you search, you can search only the working set that holds the code.

- Open Search dialog (ctrl+h)
- Change search scope to Working Set
- Click Choose ...
- Click New to create a new Working Set with the what you want searched (or Add All and then remove the ones you want filtered

Comment: Derived does not work for me. Different working set for test and src is really silly solution. Excluding /test/ package from building patch is much better. I have already mutliple working set (> 10) for different maven projects in one workspace

Comment: @Anton Excluding them from your build path won't exclude them from your search results. I'm just giving you options.

Comment: Actually it will. I'm talking about java search, call hierarchy etc.

Comment: I like the working sets recommendation; I didn't realize one could add project subfolders to a working set!